# Threading Set priority to Normal and on the called method Set to BelowNormal

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a certain thread say,

```
System.Threading.Thread archiveThread = new System.Threading.Thread(_archive);
archiveThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal;
```

which is set to `ThreadPriority.Normal`. When I call a certain function in `_archive()` on a separate class, it resets the `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;`

Regardless of the reason why I need to 'reset' the priority, what is the OS response on this? will the `ThreadPriority.BelowNormal` override the `Normal` initially declared `ThreadPriority`? Or will it keep the original `Normal` settings?

TIA

---

------------- SIMULATION ----------

```
namespace ThreadPoolNumThreads
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TPoolNumThreads t = new TPoolNumThreads();
            t.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    class TryResetThreadPriority
    {
        internal void Reset()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
        }
    }

    class TPoolNumThreads
    {
        internal void Start()
        {
            Thread monitor = new Thread(StartMonitor);
            monitor.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            monitor.Start();
        }

        private void StartMonitor(object obj)
        {
            ArrayList thisArray = new ArrayList();


            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" -----------> Threads.Priority {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Priority);

                TryResetThreadPriority myTry = new TryResetThreadPriority();
                myTry.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine(" -----------> Threads.Priority {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Priority);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread priority is a mutable state of the thread. If something changes the priority, then that's the new priority for the thread.

So, yes…if the thread's priority is changed to `BelowNormal`, then for as long as it has that priority, that's the priority used for scheduling.

You should note that a managed thread may or may not correspond exactly to an OS thread. So it's more useful to consider what the *framework* does with the thread priority. The framework may of course delegate all this to the OS, but the framework has the final say on the implementation detail. There are a lot of different implementations of .NET around now. :)

Finally, you didn't ask and you may already be aware, but there may be a good reason the function you called reduced the thread priority. This is a common technique for long-running CPU-intensive threads, allowing such a thread to do its work without interfering with other normal-priority tasks (such as the user interface). Setting the priority back to `Normal` usually should be done only when such a thread is no longer busy with the CPU-intensive task.

(Of course, commonly such tasks are given their own dedicated thread anyway, rendering moot the priority question since no other processing is even done on that thread).

Comment: Thanks. I just did my simulation and confirmed that what you mentioned `if the thread's priority is changed to BelowNormal, then for as long as it has that priority, that's the priority used for scheduling`. Also, the primary reason I set this 'background' task is to not interfere user reads and/or writes to the database. But that is by far part of the design, regardless, you completely answered my question and with other details regarding framework and OS stuff! Kudos to that :)